# Retain cached credentials after rejoin

Tags: windows-10, vpn, active-directory, cache, winlogon.exe

I'm trying to create a script that unjoins (adds to workgroup) and then rejoins to the domain for people that work via VPN but have a deleted computer account in AD.

This will add the machine to a workgroup (batch, yes I am aware there is Remove-Computer but that gives me some issues):

`start /B /W wmic.exe /interactive:off ComputerSystem Where "Name='%computername%'" Call UnJoinDomainOrWorkgroup FUnjoinOptions=0`

And this will create the computer account and join to the domain (Powershell).

`Add-Computer -DomainName "MyDom" -OUPath "OU=My,OU=OU,DC=My,DC=Dom" -Force`

However, when you reboot after rejoining, it appears that the previously interactive logon cached credentials are not valid anymore. Upon further inspection, the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY\Cache` is empty. I tried taking a backup and after the join placing these back but that did not seem to work. It gives me the following error when logging in.

`We can't sign you in with this credential because your domain isn't available. Make sure your device is connected to your organization's network and try again. If you previously signed in on this device with another credential, you can sign in with that credential.`

Is there a way to backup cached interactive logon credentials or prevent the clearing from happening?

Comment: You need to authenticate to the domain first. You can do that by creating a VPN profile that is available to all users. When that is done, and you are on the logon screen, the bottom right of the screen will have an icon you can click that will first make a VPN connection and then login using the same credentials. For this to work, the VPN login must be the same as the AD login though, but it will also make sure that those who work remote, will always get group policy updates if they login using this method.

Comment: Our security team unfortunately does not allow a direct tunnel, company policy requires user based MFA.

Our VPN will only work after winlogon, that's why we need the cached creds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by leveraging `Test-ComputerSecureChannel -Repair`, It does seem to rejoin aswell

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-computersecurechannel?view=powershell-5.1

Note: The user that performs the repair, must have "join to" permissions set to the object.